# CSS wrapping text with overflow hidden div not working?

Tags: html, css

In my css,i  write a class style `overflow : hidden`.My div contains a small image and some paragraph text. if the overflow is hidden in the sense the word wrap doesn't work. if i remove,it works. but i need both overflow hidden and also word wrap.

```
.img-block_100 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.img-block_100 img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.ee-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 140px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 250px;
}
```

please see what i tried: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UI_Designer/u4y87qsj/1/)**

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: @APAD1 Try removing `overflow: hidden`, then you will see.

Comment: If I remove `overflow:hidden;` the full text becomes visible, as would be expected.

Comment: @APAD1 : i need `overflow:hidden;` and wrap text both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `overflow: hidden` was clearing the floated `img` element.

One solution would be to wrap both of the elements and then add `overflow: hidden` to the wrapper. In doing so, the floated `img` isn't being cleared, and the text wraps *around* the `img` as expected.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/qtfb8sen/)

```
.content-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
    height: 140px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```